# How to understand these integrals with DiracDelta?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Namely,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
(*2 Sqrt[2]*)
```

and

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2, 0], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
(*8 Sqrt[2] DiracDelta[0]*)
```

The latter one is very impressive.

Addition. Also `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` is calculated formally as the iterated integral. It's unclear whether the double integral exists in this case and how that double integral is defined. Here is an example: `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` performs 4, but `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {y, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}]` produces `-2 (HeavisideTheta[-I] + HeavisideTheta[I] -     3 (-1 + HeavisideTheta[2 - I Sqrt[2]] +        HeavisideTheta[2 + I Sqrt[2]]))`.

Comment: DiracDelta[y - x^2, 0] is equal to DiracDelta[y - x^2] DiracDelta[0] and DiracDelta[0] is not a defined quantity, so MMA simply leaves it alone.

Comment: @DanielHuber: It's unclear how to understand the product `DiracDelta[u] *DiracDelta[v]` , Does the one exist on the plane `u,v`  at all ? [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function ) says about the direct product. Thank you anyway.

Comment: DiracDelta[u] *DiracDelta[v] only makes sense in an integral, e.g.:  Integrate[f[u,v] DiracDelta[u] *DiracDelta[v] ,{u,-1,1},{v,-1,1} ] == f[0,0]. On the other hand, the symbol DiracDelta[0] does not make sense.

Comment: @DanielHuber: You wrote"DiracDelta[u] *DiracDelta[v] only makes sense in an integral". Sorry, but [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html) says nothing about it. I will be waiting for a rich in content replies of you. Also, does `DiracDelta[y - x^2, 0]` make sense?

Comment: DiracDelta is NOT a function but a distribution. The math help is not the place to learn basic concepts. I think you should get a math book and digest it.

Comment: @DanielHuber: I repeat: does `DiracDelta[y - x^2, 0]` make sense? does its integral over the three-dimensional cube $[-2,2]^3$ make sense?

Comment: Please read my first answer again and try to understand it. DiracDelta[0] is nonsense! Even if you integrate over any number of dimensions, it is still nonsense. Get a math book.

Comment: @DanielHuber: which textbooks on the topic do you read and can recommend ones?

Comment: The downvoter, can you present your answer? TIA.

Comment: I do not want to give advice without good knowledge, I do not know a good book. But try to ask this question on the mathematics stackexchange forum.

Comment: @DanielHuber: These are Mathematica questions: what does mean `8 Sqrt[2] DiracDelta[0]`? why two iterated integrals `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` and `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {y, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}]` produce the different answers `4` and `-2 (HeavisideTheta[-I] + HeavisideTheta[I] -     3 (-1 + HeavisideTheta[2 - I Sqrt[2]] +        HeavisideTheta[2 + I Sqrt[2]]))`?

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down the first integral first.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

And although Mathematica help files may not say so, this is the same as

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2]*DiracDelta[z] , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Maybe I haven't looked enough, but the only place I have seen the first form is with Mathematica.

Look at the z integral

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2]*DiracDelta[z], {z, -2, 2}]
(*DiracDelta[y - x^2]*)
```

This is correct because `DiracDelta[z]` is the same as `DiracDelta[z - 0]` and the limits of the `z` integral include `z == 0`, so the `z` contribution to the integral is `1`.

Next do the y integration.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[y - x^2], {y, -2, 2}] // Simplify[#, x ∈ Reals] & 
(*HeavisideTheta[2 - x^2]*)
```

The comes from the integral of the DiracDelta is the HeavisideTheta and only the upper limit contributes.  You can plot `HeavisideTheta[-x^2 - 2]` to see why.

Finally we have the integral over `x`.

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[2 - x^2], {x, -2, 2}]
(*2 Sqrt[2]*)
```

which gives the final answer.

The second integrand is the same as `DiracDelta[y - x^2]*DiracDelta[0]` and since DiracDelta[0] is meaningless it goes outside the integral and is left unevaluated.

The integral over z becomes `4` instead of `1` since it is by itself, and integrals over `y` and `z` are the same as the first integral.  So we end up with a numerical factor `4` times that of the first integral with an extra `DiracDelta[0]` attached.

David Griffiths `Introduction To Electrodynamics` has numerous examples of DiracDelta integrals and so does J D Jackson's `Classical Electrodymanics` book.

Comment: Thank you for yuor opinion.  Does the answer `8 Sqrt[2] DiracDelta[0]` mean the integral does not exist?  In that case the error communication should be produced. Does the integral of `DiracDelta[y-x^2,0]` over the cube in three dimensions `x,y,z` make sense at all? How about  the different values of `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` and `Integrate[DiracDelta[y - Sqrt[x]], {y, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}]`? There are questions, but there are not answers.

Comment: I looked in David Griffiths, Introduction To Electrodynamics, especially, "The Three-Dimensional Delta Function" on pp. 50-52. He says nothing about the integrals of such kind.  The development of the theory of distributions was caused by the problems which arised when primitive approach was used. I don't find any definite  integrals with $\delta$ -distribution in W. Rudin and Encyclopedia of Mathematics.

Comment: I will not get into the difference between the physicist's view and the mathematician's view of the $\delta$ function.  I know it was invented by a physicist to solve physics problems.  Yes, `DiracDelta[0]` is nonsense, and any integral that includes it is nonsense.  I don't think it should be flagged as an error.  Mathematica  doesn't know what it is, but it is independent of $x$, $y$, or $z$, takes it out of the integral and leaves it unevaluated, as it should.  Your question about other integrals should be a separate question.  You should not expect to find your exact integral in any book.

Comment: My opinion is only about what I think of the books.  My evaluation of the integrals is not opinion, but merely explains the answers.

Comment: What real physical situation does your first integral represent?  I already know your second integral has no physical significance.